# How do I join 1 table with few rows from another table?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables, "pages" and "custom_fields".

**pages**

```
--------------------------------------------------
|   id    |     title   |   
--------------------------------------------------
|    1    |     about   |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**custom_fields**

```
--------------------------------------------------
|   id    |     page   |  field   |   output    
--------------------------------------------------
|    1    |     1      |   color  |     red
--------------------------------------------------
|    2    |     1      |   shape  |    square
```

I want to join the 1 row from "pages" with all relevant rows from "custom_fields". but if I use a simple join it gives me just one of them. i want to make a smarter join that will make the query like this

**pages after join**

```
--------------------------------------------------
|   id    |     title   |   color    |    shape
--------------------------------------------------
|    1    |     about   |    red     |    square
--------------------------------------------------
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please provide your query. Simple JOIN should suffice to get the result you show.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you should use two join with the same table each one for a field

```
select a.id, a.title, b.output as  color, c.output as shape
from pages 
inner join custom_fields b on a.id = b.page and b.field='color'
inner join custom_fields c on a.id = c.page and c.field='shape'
```

or as suggested  by @alex  if one of the field type is missing you could use left join

```
select a.id, a.title, b.output as  color, c.output as shape
from pages 
left join custom_fields b on a.id = b.page and b.field='color'
left join custom_fields c on a.id = c.page and c.field='shape'
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `LEFT JOIN` so if we have only `color` or `shape` set for the page -query will still bring results

Comment: @alex  .. correct  .. and useful .. answer  updated  with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dfe66/2

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, 
    color.output as color,
    shape.output as shape
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN custom_fields color 
  ON p.id = color.page AND color.field='color'
LEFT JOIN custom_fields shape 
  ON p.id = shape.page AND shape.field='shape'
```